# How do I fix my "illegal start of type" and "<identifier> expected" errors at my return statement?

Tags: java, return, expression, identifier

I know it has something to do with my bracket placement, but I am not sure where the error is occurring. Keep in mind this is a 2nd method within my class.

```
import java.util.Scanner*;
import java.util.Arrays.*;
public class BasicMathTest
{
//Creates an array to store the numbers that will be used in the math 
problems
int alpha[] = {4, 8, 10, 15, 25, 30};
int beta[] = {2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 10};
double Problems = alpha.length;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to this Math Quiz. Here you will add, subtract, multiply and divide!");

    //Ask the user to choose their type of problem
    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Select Addition (1), Subtraction (2), Multiplication (3) or Division (4): ");
    int Selection = kbReader.nextInt();
    
    //Calculates the users score
    double score = Selection * 100 / Problems;
    System.out.println("Your score on the test: " + score + "%");
}
    
public static double Selection ()
{
    int score = 0; //Stores the number of correct answers
    int correct; //Stores the correct answer
    for (int i = 0; i < Problems; i++)
    {
        if (Selection == 1)
        {
            System.out.println(alpha[i] + " + " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] + beta[i];
        }
        else if(Selection == 2)
        {
            System.out.print(alpha[i] + " - " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] - beta[i];
        }
        else if (Selection = 3)
        {
            System.out.print(alpha[i] + " * " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] * beta[i];   
        }
        else if(Selection == 4)
        {
            System.out.print(alpha[i] + " / " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] / beta[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
return score;
}
```

```
Output: E:\Xinox Software\JCreatorV4LE\MyProjects\CreateTask\BasicMathTest.java:52: illegal start of type
    return score;
    ^
E:\Xinox Software\JCreatorV4LE\MyProjects\CreateTask\BasicMathTest.java:52: <identifier> expected
    return score;
                ^
2 errors
```

Comment: First problem == You have forgotten an opening braces at Selection==4.

Comment: I added the braces but the error still remains

Comment: Can you edit and show us some expected results and the error stack trace ?

Comment: Also use rather else if (Selection **==** 3)

Comment: ok I posted my whole code and i fixed the selection 3

Comment: score will always be = 0. I think score = correct.

Comment: type of score is **double**

Comment: No, score will be the Selection multiplied by 100 and divided by the number of problems

Comment: So remove score inside the method Selection(). Then let me suggest you a way to call method Selection().

Comment: There is a really problem with your problem. Can you explain it clearly. Because your algo is not doing what I Understand

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- you forgot an opening braces at "Selection == 4" if.
- Write **"=="** instead of **"=""" in "**else if (Selection **==** 3)**"
- type of score is **double**

Could you show us how you use **score** var ?

Look at this and let me know if it is right :

```
public static double Selection ()
{
    double score = 0; //change from int to double
    int correct; //Stores the correct answer
    for (int i = 0; i < Problems; i++)
    {
        if (Selection == 1)
        {
            System.out.println(alpha[i] + " + " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] + beta[i];
        }
        else if(Selection == 2)
        {
            System.out.print(alpha[i] + " - " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] - beta[i];
        }
        else if (Selection == 3)
        {
            System.out.print(alpha[i] + " * " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] * beta[i];   
        }
        else if(Selection == 4) 
        { // missing brace
            System.out.print(alpha[i] + " / " + beta[i]);
            correct = alpha[i] / beta[i];
   
        }
        
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    
    return score;
}
```